# How can I pipe output, from a command in an if statement, to a function?

Tags: bash, nextcloud

I can't tell if something I'm trying here is simply impossible or if I'm really lacking knowledge in bash's syntax. This is the first script I've written.

I've got a Nextcloud instance that I am backing up daily using a script. I want to log the output of the script as it runs to a log file. This is working fine, but I wanted to see if I could also pipe the Nextcloud `occ` command's output to the log file too.

I've got an `if` statement here checking if the file scan fails:

```sh
if ! sudo -u "$web_user" "$nextcloud_dir/occ" files:scan --all; then
    Print "Error: Failed to scan files. Are you in maintenance mode?"
fi
```

This works fine and I am able to handle the error if the system cannot execute the command. The error string above is sent to this function:

```sh
Print()
{
    if [[ "$logging" -eq 1 ]] && [ "$quiet_mode" = "No" ]; then
        echo "$1" | tee -a "$log_file"
    elif [[ "$logging" -eq 1 ]] && [ "$quiet_mode" = "Yes" ]; then
        echo "$1" >> "$log_file"
    elif [[ "$logging" -eq 0 ]] && [ "$quiet_mode" = "No" ]; then
        echo "$1"
    fi
}
```

How can I make it so the output of the `occ` command is also piped to the `Print()` function so it can be logged to the console and log file?

I've tried piping the command after `!` using `| Print` without success.

Any help would be appreciated, cheers!

Comment: why don't you store the output in a variable and send it to the print function you already have?

Comment: Hi, Mina! How could I do that while still ensuring the `!` check is done? Would it be something like `if ! output=$(sudo -u ...)`?

Comment: I don't think this would work. You can try getting the output first, then check if !output, which is equivalent to what you are already doing here

Comment: You can invert the condition, like `if output=$(sudo -u ...); then : nothing; else ...; fi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Print` function doesn't read standard input so there's no point piping data to it.  One possible way to do what you want with the current implementation of `Print` is:

```
if ! occ_output=$(sudo -u "$web_user" "$nextcloud_dir/occ" files:scan --all 2>&1); then
    Print "Error: Failed to scan files. Are you in maintenance mode?"
fi

Print "'occ' output: $occ_output"
```

Since there is only one line in the body of the `if` statement you could use `||` instead:

```
occ_output=$(sudo -u "$web_user" "$nextcloud_dir/occ" files:scan --all 2>&1) \
    || Print "Error: Failed to scan files. Are you in maintenance mode?"

Print "'occ' output: $occ_output"
```

The `2>&1` causes both standard output and error output of `occ` to be captured to `occ_output`.

Note that the body of the `Print` function could be simplified to:

```
[[ $quiet_mode == No ]] && printf '%s\n' "$1"
(( logging ))           && printf '%s\n' "$1" >> "$log_file"
```

See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812) for an explanation of why I replaced `echo "$1"` with `printf '%s\n' "$1"`.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much! I also really appreciate the feedback. :)

Answer (score 0):

How's this? A bit unorthodox perhaps.

```
Print()
{
    case $# in
      0) cat;;
      *) echo "$@";;
    esac |
    if [[ "$logging" -eq 1 ]] && [ "$quiet_mode" = "No" ]; then
        tee -a "$log_file"
    elif [[ "$logging" -eq 1 ]] && [ "$quiet_mode" = "Yes" ]; then
        cat >> "$log_file"
    elif [[ "$logging" -eq 0 ]] && [ "$quiet_mode" = "No" ]; then
        cat
    fi
}
```

With this, you can either

```
echo "hello mom" | Print
```

or

```
Print "hello mom"
```

and so your invocation could be refactored to

```
if ! sudo -u "$web_user" "$nextcloud_dir/occ" files:scan --all; then
    echo "Error: Failed to scan files. Are you in maintenance mode?"
fi |
Print
```

The obvious drawback is that piping into a function loses the exit code of any failure earlier in the pipeline.

For a more traditional approach, keep your original `Print` definition and refactor the calling code to

```
if output=$(sudo -u "$web_user" "$nextcloud_dir/occ" files:scan --all 2>&1); then
    : nothing
else
    Print "error $?: $output"
    Print "Error: Failed to scan files. Are you in maintenance mode?"
fi
```

I would imagine that the error message will be printed to standard error, not standard output; hence the addition of `2>&1`

I included the error code `$?` in the error message in case that would be useful.

Comment: [PIPESTATUS](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-PIPESTATUS) will contain the exit code of any failure earlier in the pipeline.

Comment: In Bash you can, but it's a bit clumsy even then. I consider it a hack for desperate situations more than a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Sending and receiving end of a pipe must be a process, typically represented by an executable command. An `if` statement is not a process. You can of course put such a statement into a process. For example,

```
echo a | ( 
  if true
  then
    cat
  fi )
```

causes `cat` to write *a* to stdout, because the parenthesis put it into a child process.

**UPDATE**: As was pointed out in a comment, the explicit subprocess is not needed. One can also do a

```
echo a | if true
then
  cat
fi
```

Comment: You don't need the `if` to be in a subprocess. The shell allows piping into and out of control structures just fine.

Comment: @tripleee: Thanks for explaining! I tried and it indeed works. After some thinking, this is indeed logical; otherwise we could not pipe into a `while` loop. I will update my answer accordingly.